# Finding $\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(3,2,1)} [1+e^{xy}\cos(x^2)\ln(z)]^{1/e^{xy}\cos(x^2)\ln(z)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have the following limit: $$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(3,2,1)} [1+e^{xy}\cos(x^2)\ln(z)]^{1/e^{xy}\cos(x^2)\ln(z)}$$

As $(x,y,z) \to (3,2,1)$ it seems the limit $\to 1^{1/0}$ so it might be $1$. However, I'm not sure if I'm on the right boat and how to properly justify my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Remember $(1+x)^{1/x}\to e$ when $x\to0$

Comment: True! I forgot about that way of getting $e$. thanks!